# Error "Class 'ZipArchive' not found" occures when the db:seed Artisan command is executed

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I have a problem when I execute following command.

`php artisan db:seed --class=QuestionTableSeeder`

The error message is as follows.

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class
>   'ZipArchive' not found
>
> at
>   /var/www/csi/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php:338
>       334|             $excel->removeCellXfByIndex(0); // remove the default style
>       335|         }
>       336|         $unparsedLoadedData = [];
>       337|
>
> > 338|         $zip = new ZipArchive();
> >         339|         $zip->open($pFilename);
> >         340|
> >         341|         //    Read the theme first, because we need the colour scheme when reading the styles
> >         342|         //~ http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1
>   PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx::load("/tmp/laravel-excel-8wjCLq8hS4qVk49C5Rg30jkE6zVErU01.xlsx")
>         /var/www/csi/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Reader.php:229
>
> 2   Maatwebsite\Excel\Reader::readSpreadsheet()
>         /var/www/csi/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Reader.php:215
>
> Please use the argument -v to see more details.

The class QuestionTableSeeder is following.

```
<?php

use App\Imports\QuestionImport;
use App\ORM\Question;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class QuestionTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run(): void
    {
        DB::statement('set foreign_key_checks=0');
        Question::truncate();
        DB::statement('set foreign_key_checks=1');
        Excel::import(new QuestionImport(), 'database/seeds/data/questions.xlsx');
    }
}
```

Please tell me the solution. What should I do to resolve the problem? I have installed php7.3-zip and php73-php-pecl-zip, then also restarted Apache but still it doesn't work.

The versions are following;

- PHP : 7.3
- Laravel : 6.6.0
- maatwebsite/excel : 3.1.17
- mysql Ver 15.1 : Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
- CentOS Linux : release 7.7.1908 (Core)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run

```
php -m | grep zip
```

If missing the "zip" show on output CLI that means you don't installed php zip extension. You should be install.

```
yum install -y zip php-zip php-pecl-zip
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It has been solved! 

When I ran this command, nothing was shown.
```php -m | grep zip```

So I executed the command which you taught me. Finally, seeder worked.

Thank you very much!